# msbuild ResolveAssemblyReferences error

Tags: msbuild, build-automation, msbuild-task, msbuildextensionpack

When i am going to publish the website in specified path using msbuild command line , its working fine but the problem is EntityFramework dll(inside bin folder of check out project) is not copying to bin folder of publish folder. it's giving below warning

E:\MSBuildTest\webtest.csproj" (default target) (2) -> ResolveAssemblyReferences target) -> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(1360,9 : warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the asse bly "EntityFramework". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors. [E:\MSBuildTest\webtest.csproj]

my xml is below mentioned

```
<Target Name="Publishold" > <RemoveDir Directories="$(PublishPath)" ContinueOnError="true" /> <MSBuild Projects="$(CheckOutPath)\$(ProjectFile)" Properties="WebProjectOutputDir=$(PublishPath); OutDir=$(PublishPath)\" /> </Target>
```

---

pls let me know how to solve this issue??